# Would It Be Possible To Use The "Share Data Contract" For UWP To Upload Via The Instagram App On Unsupported Upload Devices Running Windows 10?

Tags: c#, uwp, instagram

This is probably a really stupid question to many of you out there but I personally don't know and would like to understand, is it possible to use the share data contract for UWP to share and upload photos to the Instagram Windows 10 app.
As I am aware only touchscreen devices running windows 10 can publish videos and photos to Instagram natively so if it works would be very handy as it would allow unsupported devices to upload and share content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have installed the Instagram app on your devices, you will find that it has registered protocol in the system.

[image]

Then you could use the UWP [Share data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-to-app/share-data#choose-data) APIs to share images to Instagram.

[image]

Here’s MS official [Sharing content source app sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/ShareSource).